# "ten meatballs more" or "ten more meatballs"

Tags: word-order, noun-phrases

> Your grandfather called and he said he will come for dinner you must cook **ten more meatballs** for him.
>
> Your grandfather called and he said he will come for dinner you must cook **ten meatballs more** for him .
>
> I think he will give me one more dollar.
>
> I think he will give me one dollar more.

Is there any difference between ten meatball more or  ten more meatball or one more dollar and one dollar more . I mean when changing place of more does the meaining change?

Answer (score 0):

In your "dollar" example, both placements of "more" are acceptable and mean the same thing. My feeling (and this may be regional) is that placing "more" last is less common.

In your "meatball" example, placing "more" between "meatballs" and "for" is not idiomatic. It will be understood, but it will sound odd. I cannot give a detailed explanation of when "more" must not follow the noun. All I can say is that if you never put "more" after the noun, you are very unlikely to err.